# Difference between AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the difference between AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal for NIntegrate function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this sentence from the Mma help system is almost enough:

> With PrecisionGoal->p and
>   AccuracyGoal->a, Mathematica attempts
>   to make the numerical error in a
>   result of size x be less than
>   (10^-a)+Abs[x] 10^-p.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that AccuracyGoal -> a means "Try to get a correct digits after the decimal point", whereas PrecisionGoal -> p means "Try to get p correct significant figures in the result".

Comment: @AndrewMoylan "PrecisionGoal -> p means "Try to get p correct significant figures in the result"" "correct significant figures" or just "significant figures" ?

Comment: @LowFieldTheory Correct significant figures

Comment: So AccuracyGoal is for absolute error and PrecisionGoal is relative error.  Remenber Accurary - Absolute.